# Show Excel File Contents as HTML Table Angular

Tags: html, excel, angular, typescript

I am trying to import an Excel File and show it's contents as a table within the web-app

What I have so far:

**read-excel.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import * as xlsx from 'xlsx';
const { read, utils: { sheet_to_json } } = xlsx;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-read-excel',
  templateUrl: './read-excel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./read-excel.component.css']
})

export class ReadExcelComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() {}

ngOnInit () {


}

$mport(data: any, options: xlsx.ParsingOptions): any[][] {
    const workBook: xlsx.WorkBook = read(data, options)
    const workSheet: xlsx.WorkSheet = workBook.Sheets[workBook.SheetNames[0]]
    return sheet_to_json(workSheet, {header : 1, raw: true})
}

}
```

and in my **read-excel.component.html**

```html
<div>
<h2> Read Excel Files</h2>
<input  type="file" id="input" (change)="$mport()">
<div id='result-table'></div>
<pre id='result'></pre>


</div>
```

however, when I import the file, I am met with the error `Error: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined` in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-read-and-export-excel-demo) example

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

onFileChange(evt: any) {
    /* wire up file reader */
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(evt.target);
    if (target.files.length !== 1) throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      /* read workbook */
      const bstr: string = e.target.result;
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });

      /* grab first sheet */
      const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];

      /* save data */
      this.data = <AOA>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1 }));
      console.log(this.data);
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);
  }


  export(): void {
    /* generate worksheet */
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(this.data);

    /* generate workbook and add the worksheet */
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');

    /* save to file */
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, this.fileName);
  }
```

Comment: thank you this solution worked perfectly, a couple of questions I guess, I don't thing I've ever encountered the `DataTransfer` type would it be too much trouble to get an explanation of what that is? And also, would this potentially work for something like a CSV file?

Comment: @Banani720 it works with csv files also. Try with the example. Upload any csv file. It works.. Try it

Comment: just did and it works only thing is it does not take into account empty cells

Comment: but that is something I can hopefully workout on my own greatly appreciate the help